# Postmaster Parcel submitting to localhost

Tags: postmaster

Whenever I try and save a Parcel I created, the form just returns to localhost.  I am not working locally, so I am not sure why it would go to that.

I am using:

EE 2.7
Postmasger 1.4.3

I also have the latest Matrix, Assets and Zenbu installed.

Answer (score 1):

Postmaster uses front-end actions to save parcels, and it gets the URL for that action from your site preferences. Check the value of **URL to the root directory of your site** (found under **Admin → General Configuration**) - my guess is that it's still set to `localhost` from when you were in development.

Comment: Derek's answer is correct. If your config is correct and you want to override the value to something else, you can open the config/postmaster_config.php and override the value to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I actually had the correct settings. This was never a local project but always on a staging server.  How do I change the config file?  Do I just put the base URL in it or does it need the path?